# React fetch data from API gives error Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm using a React Hook to fetching data from a JSON object by using the native fetch method.

```
const COVID_API_URL = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";
const [infected, setInfected] = useState([]);

async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch(COVID_API_URL);

  response.json().then(response => setInfected(response));
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);

console.log(infected.Global.TotalConfirmed);
```

When I console.log the value from TotalConfirmed, I get the correct result, but when I refresh the browser, I keep getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'TotalConfirmed' of undefined
```

Anyone know why this is happening? I'm using Gatsby.js default starter, does this have anything to do with this?

Comment: I fail to understand how the accepted answer solves the problem, because the propblem here was that you are accessing a value that doesn't exists. Don't assume that you'll always get the correct data, always validate your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the value for `infected` state arrives **asynchronously**. What you can do is using `useEffect` hook.

Try as the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(infected.Global.TotalConfirmed);
}, [infected]);
```

By doing this `useEffect` callback will be triggered once `infected` value is changing - API call responses - so after `setInfected(response)` updates the value of `infected` state.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first time you access `infected` it is still undefined, all you need to do is validate the variable before using it. You don't need another `useEffect`.

```
console.log(infected && infected.Global && infected.Global.TotalConfirmed);
```

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const COVID_API_URL = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";

function App() {
  const [infected, setInfected] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  function fetchData() {
    fetch(COVID_API_URL)
      .then(jsonResponse => jsonResponse.json())
      .then(response => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setInfected(response);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log("error", e);
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(infected && infected.Global && infected.Global.TotalConfirmed);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>COVID-19 Summary</h1>
      {isLoading && <p>Getting data...</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new state like in my example isFetched then set it's default value to false

```
const [isFetched,setIsFetched] = useState(false);
```

and then use the setIsFetched function after your setInfected(response)
and finally you can check if isFetched is true then use your api data(infected state) in your code.

```
const COVID_API_URL = "https://api.covid19api.com/summary";
const [infected, setInfected] = useState([]);
const [isFetched,setIsFetched] = useState(false);

async function fetchData() {
  const response = await fetch(COVID_API_URL);

  response.json().then(response => 
  {      
     setInfected(response));
     setIsFetched(true);
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

then when you want to show api data on page you do:

```
{
  isFetched ?
  // use api data : null
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was also having this issue, even after using axios. Its easy to fix, you just need to add if else statement before return. like this

```
`if(myArray.length > 0){
return (data and everything)}
else{return <h1>Loading</h1>}`
```